# "a scandal, crime, or tragedy that journalists thought would sell papers" (the usage of 'that')

Tags: conjunctions

> "a scandal, crime, or tragedy that journalists thought would sell papers"

The 'that' is not a relative pronoun, then what is it called? Or is this idiomatic expression?

edit: 'that clause' is a relative clause.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't a relative pronoun? Grammarly gives _She finally visited the coffee shop that had such great reviews_ as an example of _that_  as a relative pronoun.

Comment: @KateBunting Your example is an easy one: the relative pronoun is a subjective case. What about my example? What's its case?

Answer (score 2):

That is a relative pronoun, or perhaps a "[relativiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativizer)", as it functions more as a conjunction than a pronoun.

It introduces the relative clause "journalists thought would sell papers", ie journalists thought this scandal, crime or tragedy would sell papers.  The noun phrase that is being modified is the implicit object of the verb 'thought'.

Comment: What do you think about my example case: subjective or objective case or possessive case ? I've known relative pronoun has 3 cases as I mentioned. I visited the relativiser link you provided here, and they say all relative pronouns. In English, what type of thing is this and what grammarians call this conjuncton?

Comment: None of the words are marked for case.  In particular "that" isn't marked for case (as I note, it is more like a conjunction than a pronoun).  This is a "object relative clause" because the modified NP is the implied object of the verb in the relative clause.   Different people have different analysis of this structure, but "Relativiser" seems be a fairly uncontroversial term for the word "that" in this structure.

Comment: Now I think that if we get rid of 'journalists thought', then the 'that' in question is a subjective case which has a verb: 'would+sell'. James K Do you agree with me?

Comment: The word "that" doesn't have any case. It is certainly not marked for case.  Other relativisers (like who/whom) are marked for case,   But "that" is like a conjunction and there isn't any case.  But I sort of see what you are saying.  In "A scandal that would sell papers"  The modified noun is the implicit subject of the verb "would".

Comment: What about this: the man who is tall, the man that is tall (both of them are subjective here)—they have a verb, 'is'

Comment: The word "that" doesn't have any case.  It is certainly not marked for case. The word "who" does have marked case (and "who" is the subject form, although modern English doesn't strictly enforce this rule).   In those examples,  "the man" is the implied subject of the relative clause "is tall".

Comment: You know, 'who' is replaced by 'that' in my example. If 'who' is subjective, then 'that' is also subjective.

Comment: @BEBYGONES, you may choose to regard _that_ as marked for case all you like, but James has told you three times that _that_ is not marked for case. Historically, _that_ here was a complementizer, which occurred _together with_ the relative word (who, which, etc). But in modern English, apart from certain expressions in some dialects, at least one of the two must be omitted (both may be if the relative is not acting as subject). The only relative pronoun which is marked for case in English is _who_, and not for all speakers. _That_ is never marked for case.

Comment: @ColinFine Let me say 'function' instead of 'case': a person who is tall=a person that is tall(who is subjective and 'that' functions in the same way as 'who' which is a subjective case.

Comment: It does in that instance. In _the man that you saw_ it doesn't. So?

Comment: @ColinFine In your exampe the 'that' is an objective case which functions as 'whom'.

Comment: So in other words you are insisting on importing into English a bit of grammar which it does not possess. Congratulations. So presumably, in _the box that I put it in_, "that" is marked as illative.